# Why Tor Project and Guardian Project don't update Fdroid and Google play repos?

Tags: android, torproject.org

I want to speak about Tor Browser for android.
On official website https://www.torproject.org/download/#android last version is Tor 9.0
On Google Play last version is 68
On F-Droid with Guardian Project's repos last version is 60.
Why they don't update their repos ?